# Optimisation of huge tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, web

I have to make a table in my MySQL database.
This table will take about 600 000 lines. So i want the better time of access.
My question is what is the better thing bettwen :

- have a VarChar column with the status of the person (like "Client", "Following", ...)
- have an Integer column that is a foreign key key to an other table that contains all possibles status

Comment: I'd say the latter. It will also help you to add/update/edit/remove statuses with ease in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an integer column that is a foreign key and then do the **Hash partition** on that. This will optimize your searching time on record .

For knowledge about partition : [Click Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29)

Here is example of how do it Hash Patition:

```
create table emp2 (
   empno number(4), 
   ename varchar2(30), 
   sal   number
) 
partition by hash(empno) (
  partition e1 tablespace emp1, 
  partition e2 tablespace emp2, 
  partition e3 tablespace emp3,
  partition e4 tablespace emp4
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! What is Hash partiton ? Is it what we called Indexes ?

Comment: No, Both are different. See above.